# Get details of attached HDMI output?

Tags: java, android, chromecast, hdmi

I understand its possible to detect if the device (tablet) is plugged in to a HDMI output, but is there a way to get any more information?

Along with this, can Chromecast gather any of this information when it is plugged into a TV?

Comment: What's the context for Chromecast?  What do you want to do with the info?

Comment: They are to be installed in venues on specific screens. We need a way to track if the clients are using more then the alloted chromecasts and/or on screens they shouldn't be.